# Symbol’s function definition is void: org-mks

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

Im on Org-mode 9.3.6 with Emacs 26 and upon pressing C-c cfor capture templates, I get

> org-capture-select-template: Symbol’s function definition is void:
>   org-mks

the stacktrace says

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function org-mks)
  org-mks((("n" "Notes" entry (file "~/mega/org/notes.org") "* %?\nEntered on %U \n %i") ("t" "Todo" entry (file+headline "~/mega/org/gtd.org" "Tasks") "* TODO %?\n %U \n%i") ("g" "Godo" entry (file "~/mega/org/gcal.org") "* TODO %^{Description} %^t%?\n %i" :prepend t :immediate-finish t) ("w" "Writing log" table-line (file "~/mega/org//workrecord.org") "|%U|%A||%?|" :prepend t :kill-buffer t)) "Select a capture template\n=========================" "Template key: " (("C" "Customize org-capture-templates") ("q" "Abort")))
  org-capture-select-template(nil)
  org-capture(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-capture nil)
  #<subr call-interactively>(org-capture nil nil)
  apply(#<subr call-interactively> org-capture (nil nil))
  call-interactively@ido-cr+-record-current-command(#<subr call-interactively> org-capture nil nil)
  apply(call-interactively@ido-cr+-record-current-command #<subr call-interactively> (org-capture nil nil))
  call-interactively(org-capture nil nil)
  command-execute(org-capture)
```

can someone tell me whats going on please?